# Not enough priviliges to edit files on his/her home dirve

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, security, network-share

Just wondering if anyone could help me out on why a user is unable to edit anything on its mapped Home Drive. 
This is what I currently did.  (OS Windows 2008 Standard R2)

In AD I setup a home address and mapped it to an O:\ drive with location \ServerNAme\Fileshare\%UserName%

On that Folder I have done the following

1) Add full Control to %Username% under the Security Tab
2) Also add the %username% on the Sharing properties and change the properties to Read/Wirte

The drive is mapped correctly. I'm able to move around, but I'm unable to edit anything. Any thoughts?  The user is logged in via a TS Web or via RDP

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the effective permissions of the file in question, the answer should become pretty obvious. You can do this by right clicking > Properties > Security > Advanced > Effective Permissions

[image: Screencap]

Also, there's no reason to share each hold folder individually, if your share structure is `\\server\homes\%username%` then you should really just share `\\server\homes`\ and give `Everyone` Full Control in the Share permissions and control access through NTFS permissions only. Share permissions are an artifact from the Win 9x days and don't really do much, other than get in the way.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by doing the following
Added a "group" to the parent folder and provided Read only permissions under the Security tab. Selected the Change flag under the sharing properties and then Full control per %username% under each home folder. That solved my issues and also protected the user's data from been accessed by other domain users.    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you deny some groups on that folder?

Best go in security, advanced, uncheck "inerit from parent", "add the permissions", then remove what you don't need.

Sorry I don't have the real buton name my system is in french.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, but no luck... Maybe you are right I might deleted a group that needed to be there.. I will try to recreate the folder and see if it works.  Thanks

Comment: Negative. Re-creating the folder just added more groups (which is expected) but still no permissions to write to it..  odd